# postion of div wrt another div even as it scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="mainDiv">

    <span class="foregroundImage" id="foregroundImage1"></span>

    <!-- Layer Code -->

    <div class="layerDiv">

    </div>

    <!-- Layer Code -->

</div>
```

i need to position layerDiv such that

1. its should be at center of mainDiv (not at center of screen)
2. mainDiv height and width are auto , so even if i'm scrolling down it should be at visible part at center.

Comment: both horizontal and vertical ?

Comment: yes center implies both horizontal and vertical

Comment: Are you trying to use layerdiv as a center column in maindiv?

Answer (score 0):

Give a width to the layer div and then margin : 10px auto. You can chose top/bottom margin to your comfort. It can be any fixed value. Cannot be auto. And layerDiv must have a width.

Comment: layerDiv have width but mainDiv width and height is auto and depends on resolution.

Comment: layerDiv will center itself in maindiv until the width of maindiv is greater than layerDiv width.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method that finds the height and width of the main div and the height and width of the layerDiv.

- The top position of the layerDiv = half of mainDiv height - half of
  layerDiv height
- The left position of the layerDiv = half of mainDiv    width - half
  of layerDiv width

Once you have this method ready, you could call this method on document load and on scroll events via JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

For dead center box in box, try

```
$('.layerDiv')
    .css('position','relative')
    .width('90%')
    .height('90%')
    .css('left', 
        (
          0.5 * $('.mainDiv').width() 
        - 0.5 * $('.layerDiv').width()
        )
    )
    .css('top', 
        (
          0.5 * $('.mainDiv').height() 
        - 0.5 * $('.layerDiv').height()
        )
    );
```

adjust your width and height % accordingly or assign px value

for a centered box permanently in the center of the screen as scrolling, use:

```
$('.layerDiv')
    .css('position','fixed')
    .width(.9*$('.mainDiv').width())
    .height(.25*$(window).height())
    .css('left',
        (
            0.5 * $('.mainDiv').width()
            - (
                0.5 * $('.layerDiv').width()
                - $('.mainDiv').offset().left
            )
        )
    )
    .css('top',
        (
            0.5 * $(window).height()
            - (
                0.5 * $('.layerDiv').height()
                - $('.mainDiv').offset().top
            )
        )
    );
```

this would be an inner box 90% of the width of the maindiv, 25% the height of the screen, centered evenly within the div and always in the middle of the screen when scrolling

Comment: accidentally removed the innermost minus parenthesis when formatting the code, so I exaggerated the indentation to make that more clear when I put them back in. You should be able to copy/paste this in and see as described